# lwIP on STM32F107 work only with debugger (stm32cubemx)

Tags: lwip, stm32f1, stm32cubemx

I have STM32CubeMX 6.6.1 and keil 5.31

I wrote a simple program and it works properly.

After that, I enabled the ETH option from the Connectivity section and set the PHY to DP83848

I have also set the mode option to RMII and the Master clock Output has also been set

Again, after running the program, there is no problem

But when I enable LWIP (it doesn't matter if DHCP is enabled or I have set an IP), the program doesn't run.

And it stops at this line "LDR     R0, =SystemInit"

`; Reset handler Reset_Handler    PROC EXPORT  Reset_Handler             [WEAK] IMPORT  SystemInit IMPORT  __main LDR     R0, =SystemInit BLX     R0 LDR     R0, =__main BX      R0 ENDP`

When I press the F5 button several times in keil, the program runs at once and gives a ping, but when I turn on the board normally, it does not run.

What could be the problem?

Comment: That's happened just if MX_Lwip_init() called in main.c

Comment: This is a problem with keil, I used stm32cubeide and the program ran fine.